# Unable to create add migrations with EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and AzureFunctions

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, entity-framework-migrations, .net-core-2.2

I have been trying for hours to run migrations on Azure Functions with EntityFramework.Core. It throws an error:

```
PM> add-migration newmigration
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Test.API.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Test.API', version: '1.0.0'
    path: 'Test.API.dll'
```

To try to solve the problem, I updated the .net core version to 2.2.300(currently the latest) from 2.2.104.Updated the Azure functions SDK and EntityFramework to the latest too. Tried with different sql servers but still no progress. Deleted the bin and obj folders - no luck. And even delete the packet manager cache...

---

UPDATE:
The problem is than in the folder *bin/debug/netcoreapp2.2* I have another folder *bin* where the **Test.API.dll** is but the **manifest file** is in folder  *bin/debug/netcoreapp2.2*. 
If you cut and paste everything from the inner bin in *bin/debug/netcoreapp2.2*, everything works fine. Also if you go to the manifest file and explicitly add the whole path to **Test.API.dll**, it works.
But it still needs manual work, any thoughts how to make it automatically recognize the right path to **Test.API.dll**?

Comment: Can you show your manifest ? also your using statements

Comment: the manifest file is more that 3000 lines, i think is not very relevant to post it

Comment: From where is that `Test.api.dll` is coming ?

Comment: **Test.API.dll** has a path **Test.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\bin\Test.API.dll**. It seems like there is a script which moves all of common info from folder **Test.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2** in folder **Test.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\bin**. But the problem is solved manually if you change the path in the manifest file or move back the dll to **netcoreapp2.2** folder (as mentioned above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jeffhollan found a solution available here:
https://github.com/jeffhollan/functions-csharp-entityframeworkcore/blob/master/functions-csharp-entityframeworkcore/functions-csharp-entityframeworkcore.csproj

In your csproj, add theses lines:

```
   <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
     <Exec Command="copy /Y &quot;$(TargetDir)bin\$(ProjectName).dll&quot;
 &quot;$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll&quot;" />   
 </Target>
```

Hope it will help!